# Spring data mongodb remove a property from a document using MongoTemplate

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I have a document as shown below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5864ddd8e38112fd70b89893"),
    "_class" : "com.apic.models.UserReg",
    "name" : "xxx",
    "email" : "xxx.xxx@xxx.com"
    "activationToken" : "fe8376ea2dbdf61ebc"
}
```

How can I remove the property `activationToken` from it using Spring `MongoTemplate`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following example removes the property `activationToken` from documents with the email `xxx.xxx@xxx.com` using the **[`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)** update modifier:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is("xxx.xxx@xxx.com"));
Update update = new Update();
update.unset("activationToken");

// run update operation
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, User.class);
```